# Loop setTimeout with Promise

Tags: javascript, settimeout, es6-promise

To ensure that execution duration is shorter than [interval frequency](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval), I a recursive pattern for the `setTimeout` function. But if I combine it with Promise the output "The End" is executed before the `loop` ends. How to use Promise correctly, or is Promise the wrong pattern for my needs?

```js
function awaitTimeout(delay) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, delay);
  });
}

function loop(msg, i) {
  if (i == msg.length) return;
  awaitTimeout(200)
    .then(function () {
      console.log(msg.substring(0, i));
      loop(msg, i + 1);
    })
    .catch();
}

awaitTimeout(3000)
  .then(function () {
    loop("Hello World, this is a Loop.", 1);
    console.log("The End");
  })
  .catch();
```

Comment: Is `writerLoop` meant to be `loop`?

Comment: Consider using async-await

Comment: Where is your `writerLoop` function defined?

Comment: @Phil, yes I meant `loop`. Thanks for the hint, I correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really only have two problems...

1. `loop` should resolve with the recursively produced promise. It can do so by **returning** the result of the recursive call.
2. Your *"The End"* logger needs to wait for the async loop to complete.

Also, using `await` within `async` functions typically makes for cleaner code IMO.

```js
const awaitTimeout = (delay) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, delay));

// Async function
const loop = async (msg, i) => {
  if (i == msg.length) {
    return;
  }
  await awaitTimeout(20); // shortened for the snippet
  console.log(msg.substring(0, i));
  return loop(msg, i + 1); // return the recursive result
};

awaitTimeout(0) // shortened for the snippet
  .then(() => loop("Hello World, this is a Loop.", 1))
  .then(() => { // wait for it all to complete
    console.log("The End");
  });
```

---

Without using `async` functions, `loop` would look like this

```js
const loop = (msg, i) => {
  if (i == msg.length) {
    return;
  }
  return awaitTimeout(200).then(() => { // return a promise
    console.log(msg.substring(0, i));
    return loop(msg, i + 1); // return the result
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between `.then(() => loop("Hello World, this is a Loop.", 1))`  and `.then(function() {loop("Hello World, this is a Loop.", 1)})`. Because if I use second version "The End" is the first output.

Comment: Arrow functions without braces implicitly return. All you'd need to do to make it equivalent is add `return loop(...)`

Answer (score -1):

Just adding to Phil's answer: if you decide not to take the advantage of the syntactic sugar of async-await, you can use the following code. The only change needed is you need to return the promises in your loop function so you can use `.then` after the recursive promise chain is completed.

```js
function awaitTimeout(delay) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, delay);
  });
}

function loop(msg, i, resolve) {
  if (i == msg.length) return resolve;
  return awaitTimeout(200)
    .then(function() {
      console.log(msg.substring(0, i));
      return loop(msg, i + 1, resolve);
    });
}

awaitTimeout(3000)
  .then(function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      loop("Hello World, this is a Loop.", 1).then(()=>console.log('The End'))
    })
  })
  .catch();
```